# PHP include menu system - Reload not working

Tags: php, include, switch-statement

I have very simple page at the moment. The only thing that I using PHP for is a switch menu system. So in the switch system i check the variable "menu" to see what it's set to.

So for example if i load the contact info it would be

> www.mydomain.com/?menu=contact

in the php switch code under "menu" there is only one thing.

> include("contact.php");

Ok, I know this is very simple, but the problem that I am having is when i change the "contact.php" the changes won't be noticeable in the browser, not until i actually go directly to that file. So I would have to browse to www.mydomain.com/contact.php and then i see the difference. After doing that I can go back to "www.mydomain.com/menu?contact" and see the difference.

I have tried to reload, refresh and reload cache command in Firefox, Safari and Chrome. They all work the same way. How can I fix this, it's rather time consuming to refresh two pages each time I need to see the changes.

Comment: Does hitting Ctrl+F5 reload it correctly?

Comment: ajax was invented for such things. Try to use search - there is lot of info about that.

Comment: I think he just wants it for debug purposes.

Comment: No CTRL+F5 doesn't work. Not until I browse the file directly. I not sure that I would need AJAX for this. This has worked in the past, maybe it's the server. I'm hosting at one.com

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a caching system like eaccelerator or APC on your system (phpinfo(); would tell you).

What happens if you print the `time()` and `filemtime()` of the template before requiring it, it should tell you when it was last modified.

Comment: I checked out the phpinfo. Couldn't find anything about eaccelerator or APC there.